# What is the official name for the ratio of edges to nodes in a connected graph?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

In my context, the nodes are code elements and the edges are "dependencies". So I am using the term "dependency density" to refer to the ratio of edges/nodes.

Is there an official term for this ratio in a connected graph?

Comment: The handshaking lemma implies that the average degree of any node is $2|E|/|V|$, so I would call your ratio half the average degree.

Answer (score 1):

In a graph the edge density ratio refers to $|E|/{|V| \choose 2}$, edges over the number of possible edges. 
However when working with sparse graphs, where $|E| = \Theta(n)$, it is possible to work with $|E|/|V|$, to avoid having a $1/n$ factor everywhere.

So "dependency density" makes sense in your case.

Comment: Edge density is something else, namely $\frac{|E|}{|V|(|V|-1)}$